# Can I remove grid lines from Google Map (v3)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map which I've customised with a JSON style through the Google Maps v3 API Styled Maps Wizard, but there was no option to edit grid lines - they're a little awkward and don't serve much purpose, but I can't work out which parameter controls them.

This isn't related to printing the map, like other questions on the topic seem to be.

**EDIT** Picture added from geocodezip's example (see comment on question):
[image]

This is from my map, where they're more obvious and break up the picture into some arbitrary grid:
[image]

Comment: What "grid lines"?  I don't see any on my maps [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/GMapsExampleV3b.html)

Comment: Hmmm perhaps this is browser-specific, basically they show as faint grey but I've got a custom styled map with dark blue water and non-grey land, so they stand out a lot more. Pls see picture edited into the answer :-)

I'm on Chrome v29, not sure about you?

Comment: Those are the tile boundaries.  Probably a css or browser problem.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on a Chromebook (stable channel), it has some trouble with WebGL so I wouldn't be surprised if it's guilty here. Will boot up my PC and check

Comment: Yup, pristine on Windows

Comment: Probably should file an issue against Chrome on the Chromebook then (might be an API issue, but given your test, I would think not)

Comment: @LouisMaddox - did you find a solution to remove the white lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those "grid lines" are the tile boundaries.  They are the result of a css or a browser problem.  Nothing you can do about them with the API.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I had the same issue today. The map would render properly the first time, but after any interaction (scroll, zoom, etc), it looked like grid lines would appear. The problem was my zoom settings in chrome were not at 100%. 
Some other threads suggested this could be a version issue with google maps but I assume this is resolved by now.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in Chrome (even not using zoom) with my map and got a CSS solution:

```
#map [tabindex="0"] > div:first-child {
    will-change: transform;
}
```